# SVG logo drop-shadow property not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, dropshadow

Drop shadow property for SVG logo not working in IE, but working in chrome.

I have used this:

```
filter:drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px #a2a2a2);
-ms-filter:drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px #a2a2a2);
-webkit-filter:drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px #a2a2a2);
```

Comment: IE does not support it per https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: @RobertLongson
Any solution??

Comment: Use another browser that does support it, or try implementing it using SVG filters.

Comment: @RobertLongson
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SVG filter equivalent of `drop-shadow()` is [described here](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#dropshadowEquivalent).

So yours would be:

```
<filter id="drop-shadow">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"/>
  <feOffset dx="0" dy="0" result="offsetblur"/>
  <feFlood flood-color="#a2a2a2"/>
  <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
  <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode/>
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </feMerge>
</filter>
```

Put this in your SVG and refer to it using `filter="url(#drop-shadow)"` or `filter url(#drop-shadow)`.

Here's a working example.  Since your offsets are 0, you can simplify it a bit...

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="drop-shadow">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2" result="blur"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="#a2a2a2"/>
      <feComposite in2="blur" operator="in"/>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="white" filter="url(#drop-shadow)"/>
</svg>
```